# Can’t Unite/Intersect/Subtract/Exclude Shapes in Pages

Tags: macbook-pro, monterey, pages

I'm making a snare drum in pages to add to the shapes but I can't unite them.

I'm running MacOS Monterey 12.6.8, Macbook Air 13" early 2015, Pages 13.0.[image: click to enlarge]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to subtract the red shapes separately – one after another – from the purple shape.

Comment: Yes I learnt that the hard way. Took me a year to work out! Thank you